# JPA relation with fallback value

Tags: java, hibernate, jpa

I'm working with JPA and Hibernate.

I have these tables:

```
ORDER
----------------------------
ID | COL A | COL B | COL C |
 1 |       |       |       |
 2 |       |       |       |

ORDER_FLOW
----------------------------
ID | ORDER_ID | ...........|
 1 |     NULL | ...........|
 2 |        1 | ...........|
```

I'd like to generate a mapping so that the first order (order.id = 1) references the second order_flow (order_flow.id=2) and the second order (order.id = 2) fallsback to the first order_flow because of the NULL FK.

Basically i'd like to map to a default order_flow record if does not exists a specific one.

Is that an impossible mapping? Can someone suggest a better approach?

Thanks in advance!

Comment: Stupid question why do you want to do this? What's the use case?

Comment: Because I'd like to have a global order_flow configuration inherited, but also allow to specify a custom order_flow if needed

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Maybe i have found a solution, don't know if it could break something..

```java
@Entity
public class Order {
    @Id
    @GeneratedValue(generator = "uuid2")
    @GenericGenerator(name = "uuid2", strategy = "uuid2")
    @Column(columnDefinition = "BINARY(16)")
    private UUID id;

    @ManyToOne
    @JoinFormula("(SELECT of.id FROM order_flow of WHERE of.order_id = id OR of.order_id is null order by of.order_id desc LIMIT 1)")
    private OrderFlow orderFlow;
}
```

```java
@Entity
public class OrderFlow {
    @Id
    @GeneratedValue(generator = "uuid2")
    @GenericGenerator(name = "uuid2", strategy = "uuid2")
    @Column(columnDefinition = "BINARY(16)")
    private UUID id;

    @OneToOne
    private Order order;
```

Answer (score 0):

You can do it by one of following methods:

1. Trigger in DB (will potentially break your JPA code)
2. Default values in entities and default links in DB.

First one is easy and understandable, so let's talk about the second one. I'm not sure it'll actually work, but I think that it may. So, you're setting default values in DB and if the first entity is saved without attached entity it will obtain default ID of default second entity and vice versa.

Also it's possible that you'll need `@DynamicInsert` annotation to not explicitly save null on the non-nullable fk column.

Comment: Thanks @asm0dey, interesting the `@DynamicInsert` annotation, but how to map the relationship in jpa? I have tried to mix `@OneToOne` `@PrimaryKeyJoinColumn` `@JoinFormula` without success

Comment: @FrancescoSteccanella why doesn't simple `@OneToOne` work for you?

Comment: small addition to this , if you have control on the DB schema, you can add a new column to the order flow table to track down if this order flow is linked intentionally to the order or defaulted ... actually this depends upon your need, but I think this will make the mapping consistent (no more need to insert nulls) and at the same time it keeps tracking

Comment: @asm0dey because i don't want a fk to order_flow on order and furthermore i need to customize the order_flow retrieval to include the record with the null order_id column. I used a OneToOne because looks to me as the most appropriate relation, but i'm open to other approaces

Comment: @osamayaccoub thanks, but doing so i'll end to have multiple order_flow records with order_id null, the defaulted status should be deducted by the absence of a order_flow record with order_id populated

Comment: I mean that :

'ORDER_FLOW
----------------------------
ID | ORDER_ID | IS_DEFAULTED|
 1 |                  1| 1|
 2 |                  1| 0|'

I don't know if it's ok with u or will be with any benefit or not .. it depends on the business